# Is the plyr package for R not available for R version 3.0.2?

Tags: r, plyr

I tried installing the plyr package and I got the warning message saying it isn't available for R version 3.0.2. Is this true or is no? If not, why would I be getting this message? I tried using two different CRAN mirrors and both gave the same message.

Comment: I was able to uninstall and install `plyr` from the `Australia (Melbourne)` CRAN mirror in `R 3.0.2` on `Ubuntu 12.04.3` without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Look under Downloads here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html Grab the binary for your OS, and install from local binary package (see R's Packages & Data menu).

Comment: I have the same problem.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html says `plyr` is at version 1.8.3 and needs R version 3.1.0 or above. How do I know what version of `plyr` is supposed to work with R version 3.0.2 (current version for Ubuntu 14.04 LTR)?

Comment: I found a solution here: <http://askubuntu.com/questions/605586/installing-plyr-on-ubuntu-14-04>
The correct version of `plyr` (1.8-1) is available in Ubuntu as package `r-cran-plyr`. This still doesn't explain why trying to install `plyr` it from R doesn't work.

Comment: on 14.04 its only 1.8-1build1, so no luck there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is that the package is available in R (just checked this on my machine).

The particular error message that you are getting is very misleading. It is R's `catch-all' condition for anything that it doesn't understand going wrong during installation. You will get this error if you mis-spelled anything (Plyr instead of plyr) or your network connection is not working, or you are behind a proxy or whatever.

I typically get this problem when I am behind a proxy or I have mis-spelled something. But it can be because of any other number of reasons. I will suggest you make sure you can access the internet from inside R first.

If nothing works, you can always download the package from CRAN using a browser. If you are on Windows, you want the .zip version and if you are on *nix you want the .tar.gz version. (.tgz for Macs?). Then you can install it like so:

```
setwd("/path/where/I/downloaded/the/compressed/file")
install.packages("plyr", repos=NULL)
```

See if that works.